# Force derived class to implement / extend specific struct within

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I'm supposed to extend an application by adding more classes to it, as a kind of "plugins". The application takes a string parameter and attempts to instantiate an object of a class named corresponding to that string. if that succeeds, the application continues to call various specific functions from that class (e.g. `Initialize()`) and serialize a struct or class called `Data`* within.
Ideally, one such class would look like that:

```
public class SomePlugin
{
    public abstract event ChangesAppliedDelegate ChangesApplied;
    public delegate void ChangesAppliedDelegate();

    public Model Data = new Model();

    public SomePlugin()
    {
        Data.Initialized = false;
    }

    public bool Initialize()
    {
        Data.Initialized = true;
        return true;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public struct Model
    {
        bool Initialized;
    }
}
```

According to the present readme, the following things MUST exist in each such class, because the framework relies on those:

- An event called `ChangesApplied` that the framework can subscribe to.
- A serializable object called `Data`, definition and content irrelevant.
- A method `Initialize()` that will be called once an object has been instanced.

What I'm trying to achieve now is to replace that readme with a Base class, that will supposedly "guide" me or any following developer to implement those requirements as clearly as possible. Now I'm stuck at defining the Data Model.

I'd prefer to make that partial and empty, so that it does exist in the Base class and the framework can rely on that, while all derived classes can optionally populate it with content:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract Model Data;

    public partial struct Model { }
}

public class Derivate : Base 
{
    public Model Data = new Model();

    public bool Initialize()
    {
        Data.A = 1;
        Data.B = "Hello world.";
        return true;
    }
    public partial struct Model
    {
        int A;
        string B;
    }
}
```

But that gives a whole handful of compiler errors and warnings (e.g. that Derivate.Model hides Base.Model (which is not what I intended), or that *the modifier 'abstract' is not valid on fields.*, suggesting I should use properties, which brings me to getter and setters functions anyway). What would be the best way to go about achieving my ideas? Is my idea any good at all, or am I just making things more compliacted than they already are?

**UPDATE**

While this question has been on hold, I've come to the conclusion that an interface (as opposed to an abstract class) serves better to this purpose, with two major drawbacks:

- The framework application has to change the way it accesses the serializable Data.
- While a programmer is not forced to implement any struct or class, `GetData()` and `SetData()`, specifically `GetData()`'s generalized return type (`object`) imply the existance of some sort of Data object. But since the framework doesn't work with Data directly anymore, the question *how and where* to store Data becomes irrelevant (that's why I use `MyModel` instead of `Model` in the following code).

That looks like the following:

```
public interface IBase
{
    object GetData();
    void SetData(object newData);
}

public Derivate : IBase
{
    public MyModel Data = new MyModel();

    public bool Initialize()
    {
        Data.A = 1;
        Data.B = "Hello world.";
        return true;
    }

    public object GetData()
    {
        return Data;
    }

    public void SetData(object newData)
    {
        Data = (MyModel) newData;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public struct MyModel
    {
        public int A;
        public string B;
    }
}
```

*For those who read the question before a proper re-edit and clarification: I had mixed up the meaning of `Model` (the struct definition) and `Data` (the instance of Model).

Comment: This seems an X/Y problem. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can make your type generic `Base<TModel> where TModel : struct`, so in derived you can specify `Derived : Base<Model>`.

Comment: Other than an XY problem (which I do agree with), you seem to be mixing the definition of the struct itself with the definition of a property whose type is the struct.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria: (1) That's not a comment, that's an answer (2) That's not exactly what OP wants - it's tangential information at best.

Comment: @Flater because _That's not exactly what OP wants_ I posted this as a comment.

Comment: I indeed did simplify the issue here. There's an external class that requires any Derivate object to maintain a serializable object/struct called "Model", then access it for binary serialization.

Comment: @draconigen: On the closing of the answer, I do think you could do with some tips to further investigate the issue: (1) Re-evaluate why you think its necessary to define this struct inside the class, and not just outside of it (2) Remember that structs can inherit from each other (3) Look into generic classes and how they can handle inheritance (4) Look up what the XY problem is and try to avoid it in future questions - it's prone to attracting downvotes and closures because you're not asking the question you actually need answered.

Comment: Thanks @Flater, indeed I had to look up what an X/Y problem is as soon as it was mentioned the first time. I'll avoid asking questions like that in the future.

Comment: Also please post your compiler noise

Comment: This might be a good case for [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/)

Comment: As a side note, to make a `struct` with mutable fields (fields you can change) is a really bad idea. The way to handle this would be to have a constructor on the struct that sets the data and also sets the `Initialized` property to true. If the struct is just declared without the `new` keyword, then `Initialized` would default to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my take on this situation:

First the contract for the plugin:

```
public interface IModel
{
    bool Initialized { get; }
}
public interface IPlugin<TModel> where TModel: struct, IModel
{
    event ChangesAppliedDelegate<TModel> ChangesApplied;
    TModel Model { get; }
    void SetData(TModel model);
}
public delegate void ChangesAppliedDelegate<in TModel>(TModel model) where TModel : struct, IModel;
```

then a typical implementation of the contract

```
public struct MyModel : IModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Data constructor. Assumes data is initialized after this is called.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">The A value</param>
    /// <param name="b">The B value</param>
    public MyModel(int a, string b)
    {
        this.A = a;
        this.B = b;
        this.Initialized = true;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Copy construct, but with ability to flip the Initialized property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">The model to copy data from</param>
    /// <param name="initialized">Set the initialization flag here</param>
    public MyModel(MyModel other, bool initialized = true)
    {
        this = other;
        this.Initialized = initialized;
    }
    public int A { get; }
    public string B { get; }
    public bool Initialized { get; }

}

public class MyModelPlugin: IPlugin<MyModel>
{
    public MyModel Model { get; private set; }

    public event ChangesAppliedDelegate<MyModel> ChangesApplied;

    public void SetData(MyModel model)
    {
        if(model.Initialized)
        {
            this.Model =model;
            ChangesApplied?.Invoke(Model);
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle case where model isn't initialized
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, a usage example

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var plugin = new MyModelPlugin();
        plugin.ChangesApplied += (m) => Debug.WriteLine(m.Initialized ? $"A={m.A}, B={m.B}" : "Uninitialized");

        // Uninitialized model
        var model = new MyModel();
        plugin.SetData(model);

        // Initialized model
        model = new MyModel(1, "Hello SO");
        plugin.SetData(model);

        // Make a copy and check equality
        var copy = plugin.Model;
        Debug.WriteLine($"Copy is identical = { copy == model }");
    }
}
```

with the output from the debugger

```
A=1, B=Hello SO
Copy is identical = True
```

### Appendix

Required code for each model struct shown below in order for the framework to handle structures correctly. The struct needs to be immutable, and it must handle the equality operators `==` and `!=` based on the data. Finally, `GetHashCode()` needs to return unique data-driven value for use in `Dictionary` type containers.

```
[ImmutableObject(true)]
public struct MyModel : IModel, IEquatable<MyModel>
{
    ...
    #region Equality Comparison
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj is MyModel model)
        {
            return Equals(model);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(MyModel other)
    {
        return A==other.A&&
               B==other.B;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hashCode = -1817952719;
        hashCode=hashCode*-1521134295+A.GetHashCode();
        hashCode=hashCode*-1521134295+B.GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(MyModel model1, MyModel model2)
    {
        return model1.Equals(model2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyModel model1, MyModel model2)
    {
        return !(model1==model2);
    }

    #endregion
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that took me a while to comprehend. What's your opinion on sticking to structs, as opposed to switching to classes for MyModel? Wouldn't that simplify a few things, especially the drawbacks highlighted in your appendix?

Comment: @draconigen - with classes equality only refers to equal references (point to the same data) as opposed to two sets of data being equal. This would have implications further on. Additionally, you have to start worrying about `null` values and the complexity rises again. I like `struct` as data containers, as long as I don't run into synchronization problems (different parts of the code having different versions of the data). That is why it is important to make them immutable and to be careful where can a new struct be crated.

Comment: @draconigen - also the code in the appendix was auto-generated in VS2017 by the style editor. So it is not a big deal in general. I also have a snippet to generate similar code for either `struct` or `class` as I think a proper implementation of `IEquatable<T>` makes for nice an reusable code. See [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/BrMYMCk.png) for example.